# using command line to call 2 matlab files, where 2nd file depends on 1st one

Tags: matlab, command-line

I have two .m files. first file does the initialzation and load some data.
second .m file is a function and depends on the first file.

I call `matlab -nojvm -r "firstFile;secondFile(args);exit"` and it works.

but now I want to call 2nd function file several times while only call 1st file once in the beginning.

`matlab -nojvm -r "firstFile;exit"`

`matlab -nojvm -r "secondFile(args);exit"` doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to stick with specifying stuff on the command line rather than writing out a separate script, you could do:

```
matlab -nodisplay -r "firstFile; for idx = 1:7, secondFile(args); end, exit"
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call the `matlab` command, you're starting a new instance of Matlab. Previously used variables won't be available on subsequent calls. Instead just open a command line instance on Matlab once:

```
matlab -nojvm -nosplash -r
firstFile
for i=1:1000
   secondFile(args)
end
exit
```

Once you call the `matlab` command, you can type any Matlab-syntax commands you want into the command line, just like you would with the Matlab GUI.